# Unable to embed fonts in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, truetype-fonts

I'm trying to embed fonts on a PowerPoint template I'm working on, but every time I try to save it, I get an error saying that the font cannot be embedded because it's not truetype. I've looked through every slide and made sure that the troublesome font isn't there, but I still get the error. I've also tried deleting the font from my system via the registry. It's possible this issue comes from the fact that the font in question was previously used in the template, but if it's hidden or embedded already, I'm not sure how to remove it. Any help or advice would be wonderful! Thank you!

[EDIT] I'm working in Windows 10, sorry!

Comment: Take a look at these two official articles:[Embed fonts in Word or PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-fonts-in-word-or-powerpoint-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc) and [Some of your fonts can't be saved with the presentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/some-of-your-fonts-can-t-be-saved-with-the-presentation-2ba26947-5d18-4eb3-b5a9-67a58629e1b8)

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT It's weird, the fonts haven't been embedded previously, but the file has been saved as a powerpoint template, so maybe the fonts have been embedded when that was done? As of right now, the "Embed Fonts" options are not checked, and the file saves fine, but when the option is checked, the file is unable to save and we get that error saying that Verdana can't be embedded, even though Verdana isn't in the powerpoint at all.

Comment: PLEASE always mention whether you're on Mac or Windows. It matters. If Windows, go to the Home tab, click the triangle next to Replace in the Editing group and select Replace Fonts. In the dialog that opens, select Verdana under Replace: then select some other (embeddable) font under With: then click Replace.